# How to update the state of one particular element while looping through an array using map function

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

How to update the state of one particular element while looping through an array using map function.

```
<View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
       {
         this.props.addresses.map(addr => {
          return (
            <View style={{ marginRight: 10 }} key={addr.label}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.labelTextStyle}>{addr.label}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        })
      }
</View>
```

How will i update the state of the one particular element (addr.label) on firing an event?

Comment: I don't see any state in your code

Comment: what if i had onPress event for the view and in the call back I need to set the state for that particular element in an array from where the event was fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call setState in loop directly

From react docs:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

What you can do is

```
eventHandler(idx, val) {
   var newState = {}
   newState[idx] = val;
   this.setState(newState);
}
```

and in the view suppose you have a button that need to trigger the handler

```
<View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
       {
         this.props.addresses.map(addr, idx => {
          return (
            <View style={{ marginRight: 10 }} key={addr.label}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.labelTextStyle}>{addr.label}</Text>
                <Button onPress={this.eventHandler.bind(this, idx, addr.label}><Button>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        })
      }
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
array.map(itam => {
    this.setState({foo: bar});
    return 'something';
});
```

Comment: This will set the state for all the elements in an array. what if i had onPress event for the view and in the call back I need to set the state for that particular element in an array from where the event was fired?

Comment: then you need to use a method for that event like `<View onPress={this.someMethodCall.bind(this,identifier)}></View>`

Comment: now instead of changing the state inside the loop you can call the method which will be responsible for changing the state

Comment: what do you mean by identifier here? is that the key from map function?

Comment: something that you can access from the method like
`someMethodCall(param){
  this.setState({param: true});
}`

for instance if your array consists of id & value pair then sending the id will be ideal to target the exact array item from the method